# Change UIView orientation in single view app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have created multiple `UIView`s dynamically in a single view app. I need the main `UIView` to show in landscape mode.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to set the entire app to landscape only, or just rotate a view 90°?

Comment: I need entire apps to landscape

Comment: See my answer on how to change the supported orientations for your entire app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: change supported screen orientations for the entire app

To change the screen orientations your entire app runs in, click on your project in the left pane to go to project settings:

[image: Select your project]

Then:

1. Click on your iOS app target in the left pane (it'll probably be the only one there)
2. Click on the **Summary** tab at the top
3. Select the orientations you want your app to support. Click on one to enable it, click again to disable. In the screenshot, the portrait orientation *and* both landscape orientations are enabled. To make your app only support landscape, click on the portrait orientation icon to disable it.
4. Scroll down and do the same for the iPad (the settings will look the same, just in a separate section lower down the page).

[image: Choose which orientations you want]

This will make your entire app only support these screen orientations you select.

### Option 2: support different screen orientations per view

In your view controller, override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` like so:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

This will force the view to only appear in an orientation which you declare support for here. In this example, the view only supports landscape orientations. You can read the official Apple guide [**here**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .m file

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

if you want to manage all views in portrait/landscape then you need to maintain their frames manually.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. But its not working.